# How to download a zip file from link (ftp) and pass username and password?

Tags: c#, ftp, download

I want to download a file from a link, then save downloaded file in `D:\Files`.I have username and password .

How to do in `c#`(console application)?.

how to pass those link with username and password?

Comment: FTP request example: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{            
  client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
  client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.format("{0}:{1}"), user, password));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.format("Basic {0}", auth));
```